# android:onClick not working with ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard

Since today, something weird is happening with my application. Every time I click a button that has set the android:onClick attribute, I get an *IllegalStateException: Could not find a method ...*

I noticed that only happens when I enable Proguard in the file: default.properties

This is my proguard.cfg:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

The thing is that doesn't happened last week.. (I was using proguard too). Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I found another solution to this problem:
The project with problems was created with an old version of the ADT plugin (Eclipse). I created a new project with the same parameters and copied the *src/*, *res/* and *Manifest*, and problem solved!

Comment: In your post you have accidentally commented out most of the code -- not sure if that's just a typo or not.

Comment: That's the proguard file, it has /* and stackoverflow detects it as a comment..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell proguard not to mutate the method associated with your `android:onClick` tag.

Here is an example rule (taken from [the proguard website](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/examples.html)):

```
-keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass {
    void myCallbackMethod(java.lang.String);
}
```

Comment: That's it.. Thanks! I still don't understand why that didn't happen before.

Comment: I just checked and the android:onClick works in some xml but not in others.. Do you know why does that happen?

Answer (score 6):

in the example file in the android framework tools (YOUR_ANDROID_DIR/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt), you can find the following rule:

```
# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}
```

With the comment it's quite explicit.