# ProGuard broke my Android code

Tags: android, proguard

I added ProGuard to my Android project using default settings, and it broke my code.

On the first screen, I have a Button like this:

```
  <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onSaveButtonClick" />
```

And I have a method in the Class:

```
public void onSaveButtonClick(View view){
 // some code 
}
```

When ProGuard disabled, everything works just fine. When enabled, on clicking the button I get this error:

> 05-17 16:04:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method
>   onSaveButtonClick(View) in the activity class xxxx for onClick handler
>   on view class android.widget.Button with id 'xxxxx'

Any ideas why this happened?

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796190/androidonclick-not-working-with-proguard) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proguard is changing your method "onSaveButtonClick" to something like "a". It doesn't update your XML file so Android can no longer find it. You should either set your click handler programmatically (using setOnClickListener on the view) or following the advice in the linked in SO question that Keyser posted.