# Button setOnClickListener() vs android:onclick

Tags: android, button

To register an `OnClickListener` I always call `setOnClickListener(listener)` on the `Button`. Now I have seen a piece of code where the click event is defined in the layout, by using `android:onclick="nameOfMethod"` and implement the method with a `View` parameter.

Are there any differences in these two ways of adding an `OnClickListener`? Which one is recommended?

Comment: Note that using onClick the method should be in your Context. Doing that in Fragment you will have to define the method in the Activity containing the Fragment. And you will have to make sure proguard doesn't remove the methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `onClick` with function binded in XML is a bind between `onClick` and the function that it calls. The function will have only one argument in order for `onClick` to function.

An `OnClickListener` is an interface that any class could implement. Since it is an interface that any class could implement, this is more flexible.

You could easily swap one listener implementation with another if you need to.

An `OnClickListener` enables you to separate the action/behavior of the click event from the View that triggers the event. While for simple cases this is not such a big deal, for complex event handling, this could mean better readability and maintainability of the code

In other words -

XML `onClick` is good for one fixed implementation in your Java code.
`OnClickListener` is better for more complex codes and multiple buttons. But as for the basic function - they both do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any differences in these two ways of adding an OnClickListener? Which one is recommended?

No they are not different and both will work, but from my experience I don't recommend you to use the xml `onClick` option for one simple reason xml layout files were created as their name to represent layouts and represent the visual aspect of what ever you design.

Leave the java part, to the java files : )

Answer (score 0):

I had

I activity layout I could define method to call

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_hot_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClickHotWords"
        android:text="@string/search_hot"
        />
```

then in Java

```
// defined in layout/search.xml
public void onClickHotWords(View v){
    FSLogcat.d(TAG, "onClickHotWords");
    requestHotWords();
}
```

but I had to rewrite that to with
 `mSearchHotWordsLabel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`
when using that layout inside fragment.

Also there is proguard related problem with `mSearchHotWordsLabel`
see [android:onClick not working with ProGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796190/androidonclick-not-working-with-proguard)